# memory leakage and load testing

Tags: asp.net, memory-leaks, tsung

I have done a lot of research and not able to find any information about the below.

I am using asp.net 4.0, I have created a web application. I would like to know how i could check for memory leakages in the program that i have created, what tool could be used in order to do this also would like to know a good tool which could be used by me to do a load test on the same website, which tool could i use as all of the ones that have been recommend are not ideal the tools i have used for load testing are tsung and a few other free tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a memory profiler.

There are [free ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308816/any-good-free-net-profiler) as well as commercial ones, some of the better known are the [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) by RedGate, [dottrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) by JetBrains and [memprofiler](http://memprofiler.com/) by SciTech.

These all essentially hook into the running process measuring things like memory usage and more - giving you a report on the application performance and memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

I like [Selenium Grid](http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/). You can also look into [StresStimulus](http://community.stresstimulus.com/forum).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WinDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx) which comes with the Windows SDK. The below videos should direct you in a right direction:

- http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-13-WinDbg
- http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-14-WinDbg-SOS
- http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-21-WinDbg-Memory-User-Mode
- http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-22-WinDbg-Memory-Kernel-Mode